# Update application through ftp

Tags: c#, wpf, ftp

I am having strange problem while updating my application through ftp. I am uploading files to a folder in ftp by Ipswitch WS_FTP.
I am updating files in remote folder to check my code. But it is downloading old files which were rewritten in remote folder. 
Here is details. I have a folder update. Inside of this folder 2 files. version.txt and app.zip
In old files I used capital letters such as VERSION.txt, In new file small capitals.
But I can not reach new files. Why? I can reach only old files which is VERSION.txt
With app.zip the same problem, I am updating its files inside zip file. But getting old files from zip file. 
PS. I am changing files inside app.zip and uploading it to remote folder but I can not reach new files inside app.zip. I can reach only old files. The problem is refreshing of files inside app.zip. Or I have problem with cache or something else?

Comment: "small capitals"...? Using capitals to distinguish file names is always going to end is disaster.

Comment: what about app.zip??? I am updating it always. Inside it new files. But I am getting old files.

Answer (score 0):

If the server is on linux, you should note linux is file system is `camel case` (window is not), so in linux `file.txt` != `FILE.txt` and in windows are the same file. Hope this tips, helps.

Comment: I have updated my question, I have problem not with letters but with refreshing of files inside this folder.